# how can we write parametrized Test cases for android

Tags: android, parameterized, android-testing

As reference to Java JUnit doc...
http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html

I tried to implement the same in android, but did not work. Also I inherited Test class with different classes like "TestSuit", "InstrumentationTestCase", "AndoirdTestCase" but parametrization functionality could not be achieved.
Specifically I want to implement parametrized class and it should inherit from "InstrumentationTestCase"

Does android support @RunWith(Parameterized.class) ?

Comment: Which problem are you trying to solve?